# How to get and set attribute with arguments

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to write a class that allows me to record the number of zip files in a location and store that list as an attribute so I can reference it repeatedly. I don't want the check for zip files to be run automatically when the class is initialized because it takes a long time (it does more than what's written here). I have written that but now I would like to expand it with new features. I would like to add two features to it. First, I would also like the ability to recheck the path after setting the attribute (imagine I've created the class then moved more files into the directory). And secondly, I would like the ability to change the directory I look for the zip files in. Here is my original class:

```
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        self.zip_files_at_loc_ = None
        self.default_path = '~/default'

    @property
    def zip_files_at_loc(self):
        if self.zip_files_at_loc_ is None:
           self.zip_files_at_loc_ = glob.glob(self.default_path+"/*.zip")
        return self.zip_files_at_loc_
```

This doesn't do the two new features I would like. I could get rid of the attribute and just replace it with this function:

```
def get_zips(self, path=None):
    if not path:
        path = self.default_path
    return glob.glob(path+"/*.zip")
```

But this no longer stores the information, so I have to repeatedly recalculate it. How can I add the new features while keeping `zip_files_at_loc` as an attribute? This seems like a simple getter and setter approach would work but I wasn't able to add the optional path variable to the approach [at this tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php).

Comment: The normal convention is to use `_` at the beginning of the attribute name, not the end.

Comment: Where do you set `path` in the `zip_files_at_loc` function?

Comment: Sorry, I removed it. Let me edit that real quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `reset()` method that sets `self.zip_files_at_loc_` back to `None`, so the next call will recalculate.

And make the directory a parameter of the class. To change directories just use different `C` objects for each. Or reassign `c.default_path()` and then call `c.reset()`.

```
class C:

    def __init__(self, default_path = '~/default'):
        self.zip_files_at_loc_ = None
        self.default_path = default_path

    @property
    def zip_files_at_loc(self):
        if self.zip_files_at_loc_ is None:
           self.zip_files_at_loc_ = glob.glob(self.default_path+"/*.zip")
        return self.zip_files_at_loc_

    def reset(self):
        self.zip_files_at_loc_ = None
```

Comment: For the reset method, is there not a way to pass something as an argument to zip_files_at_loc? Something like zip_files_at_loc(reset=True)? I couldn't find a way (which is why I asked the question) but I was thinking there would be something more Pythonic than a reset method?

Comment: No, you can't pass parameters to a property, because you use it as an attribute, you don't call the function.